# Compiler error "incompatible types"

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I'm getting a compiler error:

> Exercise.java:47: error: incompatible types       Time endTime =
>   startTime.addMinutes(minutes);

```
                                       ^
```

required: Time
  found:    void
1 error

The method I'm trying to use is this:

```
public void addMinutes(int mins) {
    this.mins += mins;
    if (this.mins >= 60) {  // check if over
        addHours(this.mins / 60);
        this.mins = this.mins % 60;
    }
    }
```

I'm not sure why.

```
  import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Exercise {

        private String exercise;
        private int minutes;
        private Time startTime;
        private Time endTime;
        private int addedminutes;



        public Exercise(String exercisetype, int m, Time start) {
        this.exercise = exercisetype;
        this.minutes = m;
        this.startTime = start;
        }


        public String getType() {
        return this.exercise;
        }


        public int getMinutes() {
        return this.minutes;
        }


        public Time getStart() {
        return this.startTime;
        } 


        public Time getEnd() {
        Time endTime = startTime.addMinutes(minutes);
        return endTime;
        }        



        public int addMinutes(int added) {
        addedminutes = this.minutes + added;
        return addedminutes;
        }


        public Time setStart(Time newstart) {
        this.startTime = newstart;
        return newstart;
        }


        public String toString() {

        String startStandard = startTime.getStandard();
        String endStandard = endTime.getStandard();

        String toReturn = (this.exercise + " for " + this.minutes + " minutes," + " from " + startStandard + " to " + endStandard);
        return toReturn;
        }

        public boolean equals(Exercise exTwo) { 
        return exercise == exTwo.exercise && minutes == exTwo.minutes && startTime == exTwo.startTime;
        }

        private static String exercisetype;
        public static String getTypes() {
        String types = ("Exercise types: " + Exercise.exercisetype);
        return types;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where is The Time class defined? There is no import for it or code.

Comment: Your `addMinutes` method does not return anything, it is a `void` type. Your method changes the internal state of your `Exercise` object by calling `this.mins += mins;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addMinutes` does not return a value (`void` return type).  Instead, it changes the state of the Time object it is called on.

Either, change the method to return the time after it is done, like:

```
public Time addMinutes(int mins) {
    this.mins += mins;
    if (this.mins >= 60) {  // check if over
        addHours(this.mins / 60);
        this.mins = this.mins % 60;
    }
    return this;
}
```

Or change your usage to something like:

```
public Time getEnd() {
    Time endTime;
    startTime.addMinutes(minutes);
    //This seems wrong, by the way.  startTime will be modified by this call.
    endTime = startTime;
    return endTime;
}
```

Or, more simply:

```
public Time getEnd() {
    startTime.addMinutes(minutes);
    return startTime;
}
```

Comment: Or much more simply `return startTime.addMinutes(minutes);`

Comment: @Smit That was the original problem.  Since that example is meant to address the case in which the addMinutes method should remain unchanged, it will still have a void return type, so that would not be correct.

Comment: +1 I understood your point, I was talking about your `getEnd()` method return type.

Comment: Another problem: When I try to run the driver program, I get the following error:

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Exercise.toString(Exercise.java:68)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
 at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
 at pg5a.main(pg5a.java:17)

     ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Try to debug what instance is null. I mean the instance you forgot to initialized. Or better post another question with your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

`addMinutes` does not return an instance of `Time` (`void`), so you cannot assign it to `endTime`

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
Time endTime = startTime.addMinutes(minutes);
```

but you have declared addMinutes :

```
public void addMinutes(int mins)
```

Which does not return anything, so there is no return value to assign to endTime.